# Bind scope to event handler, but keep original argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I bind an an event in this way:

```
render() {
  return <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>click me</button>
}
```

But I'd need to retrieve the original argument of the `onClick` event.

```
click(evt) {
  // evt is undefined here
  this.setState({ evt: evt })
}
```

How can I make this code work?

Comment: what is the original argument?  `evt.target`? `this`?

Comment: just `evt`, the default argument passed by the `onClick` event listener

Comment: So, what is happening now?  Is `evt` not defined?

Comment: Yes because I bind just `this` to the `this.click` action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To propagate the `e` from the click event you can wrap in another function:

```
render() {
  return <button onClick={function(e) { this.click(e)}.bind(this)}>click me</button>
}
```

Or, you can use arrow functions if you are in ES6:

```
render() {
  return <button onClick={(e) => { this.click(e)}}>click me</button>
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `this` inside the wrapper function be the context of the function and not of my React component?

Comment: That is why the wrapping function is bound. `function(e) { this.click(e)}.bind(this)`

Comment: ah yes sorry I mixed the brackets